# VPN versus Azure Virtual desktop - Which is secured to access the server, application and personal data

Tags: vpn

VPN versus AVD (Azure virtual desktop) - Which is the more secured to access applications, persona data and the server.

Please provide security related and compliance related points.
Risk and any examples of issues VPN versus AVD

Need to know which is secure VPN versus AVD